# FileOutputStream does not create file

Tags: java, file, fileoutputstream

I actually checked other posts that could be related to this and I couldn't find any answer to my question. So, had to create this newly:

The file does not get created in the given location with this code:

```
    File as = new File ("C:\\Documents and Settings\\<user>\\Desktop\\demo1\\One.xls");
    if (!as.exists()) {
        as.createNewFile();
    }
    FileOutputStream fod = new FileOutputStream(as);
    BufferedOutputStream dob = new BufferedOutputStream(fod);
    byte[] asd  = {65, 22, 123};
    byte a1 = 87;
    dob.write(asd);
    dob.write(a1);
    dob.flush();

    if (dob!=null){
        dob.close();
    }
    if(fod!=null){
        fod.close();
```

The code runs fine and I don't get any FileNotFoundException!!
Is there anything that I'm missing out here?

Comment: Is `<user>` supposed to be replaced with something?

Comment: Have you replaced `<user>` with the actual user name?

Comment: Does folder **demo1** exist?

Comment: Why (a) are there two identical-but-easy-to-mistype strings instead of one, and (b) why create the FOS with a filename when you already have a `File`?

Comment: @Dave Newton Yes, i had this doubt whether FOS would create a file!! I actually tried using only FOS and it did not work though.

Comment: @user1739812 I was asking why not use the FOS ctor that takes a `File`.

Comment: @DaveNewton Thanks but I did that too. Still, the filedid not get created.

Comment: @user1739812 I'm not suggesting that it's a fix to the problem, I'm suggesting it eliminates code duplication. You need to answer the questions regarding `<user>`.

Comment: Can you show you Exception handling. An please answer that your final code doesn't have `<user>`.

Comment: @partlov I did not get your question completely. Regarding the <user>, yes, I've replaced it with the actual user name and demo1 folder also exists.

Comment: A thought that you maybe show us a `try catch` block which surrounds this code. It is difficult to understand that this is happening without any Exception.

Comment: There are no Exceptions as I've already mentioned!! The code runs fine. The only problem is that I don't see the file getting created

Comment: It is not possible for this code to fail to produce a file without an exception. Either you're looking in the wrong place or you've missed the exception output, or the file was created. NB The `exists()/createNewFile()` code is a complete waste of time and space. `new FileOutputStream(...)` already has to do that, and now you're forcing it to happen twice.

Comment: @Mercenary, how about using just file name `new File("One.xls")`?

Comment: With directories created and `<user>` replaced with real user directory as OP states I failed to replicate error (file was created)!

Answer (score 1):

You can rewrite your code like this:

```
BufferedOutputStream dob = null;
try {
    File file = new File("C:\\Documents and Settings\\<user>\\Desktop\\demo1\\One.xls");
    System.out.println("file created:" + file.exists());
    FileOutputStream fod = new FileOutputStream(file);
    System.out.println("file created:" + file.exists());
    BufferedOutputStream dob = new BufferedOutputStream(fod);
    byte[] asd = {65, 22, 123};
    byte a1 = 87;
    dob.write(asd);
    dob.write(a1);
    //dob.flush();
} 
catch (Exception ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
finally {
    if (dob != null) {
        dob.close();
    }
}
```

- In this case it is only necessary to call the topmost stream handler [close()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/FilterOutputStream.html#close%28%29) method -  the [BufferedOutputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/BufferedOutputStream.html)'s one:

> Closes this output stream and **releases any system resources** associated with the stream.
>   **The close method of FilterOutputStream calls its flush method, and then calls the close method of its underlying output stream.**

- so, the `dob.flush()` in `try` block is commented out because the `dob.close()` line in the `finally` block flushes the stream. Also, it releases the system resources (e.g. "closes the file") as stated in the apidoc quote above. Using the [finally block](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/finally.html) is a good practice:

> The **finally block always executes** when the **try block exits**. This ensures that the finally block is executed even if an unexpected exception occurs. But finally is useful for more than just exception handling — it allows the programmer to avoid having cleanup code accidentally bypassed by a return, continue, or break. Putting cleanup code in a finally block is always a good practice, even when no exceptions are anticipated.

- The FileOutputStream [constructor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/io/FileOutputStream.html#FileOutputStream%28java.io.File%29) creates an empty file on the disk:

> Creates a file output stream to write to the file represented by the specified File object. **A new FileDescriptor object is created to represent this file connection.**
>   First, if there is a security manager, its checkWrite method is called with the path represented by the file argument as its argument.
>
> **If the file exists but is a directory rather than a regular file, does not exist but cannot be created, or cannot be opened for any other reason then a FileNotFoundException is thrown**.

Where a [FileDescriptor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/FileDescriptor.html) is:

> Instances of the file descriptor class serve as an opaque handle to the underlying machine-specific structure representing an open file, an open socket, or another source or sink of bytes. The main practical use for a file descriptor is to create a FileInputStream or FileOutputStream to contain it.
>
> Applications should not create their own file descriptors.

This code should either produce a file or throw an exception. You have even confirmed that no conditions for throwing exception are met, e.g. you are replacing the  string and the demo1 directory exists. Please, rewrite this to a new empty file and run.

If it still behaving the same, unless I have missed something this might be a bug. In that case, add this line to the code and post output:

```
 System.out.println(System.getProperty("java.vendor")+" "+System.getProperty("java.version"));
```

Judging from the path, I'd say you are using Win 7, am I right? What version?

Comment: @user1739812 are you sure that the directory exists?

Comment: Yes, the directory does exist.

Comment: There are no exceptions seen in the above code and it works fine. Also, I see that it does close the file and buffered input stream (the if condns at the end).

Comment: No, I'm using Windows XP !

Comment: could you please, rewrite my version of your code to a new empty file and run? if it doesn't throw exception and it doesn't create the file then please post the java version also (see the last line of code in my post)

Answer (score -2):

Then it means there is a file already in your directory

Comment: I believe the OP is stating that no file is created.

Comment: No, the file is not present in my directory!!

Comment: No, it doesn't mean that. It means the user hasn't told us about some exception.