# FileOutputStream doesn't create file

Tags: java, eclipse, fileoutputstream

Exact duplicate of [FileOutputStream does not create file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14378898/fileoutputstream-does-not-create-file)

I'm running the following code in eclipse, which I took from that question. No file is created.

```
BufferedOutputStream dob = null;
    try {
        File file = new File("C:\\Users\\claudio\\ccc.as");
        System.out.println("file created:" + file.exists());
        FileOutputStream fod = new FileOutputStream(file);
        System.out.println("file created:" + file.exists());
        dob = new BufferedOutputStream(fod);
        byte[] asd = {65, 22, 123};
        byte a1 = 87;
        dob.write(asd);
        dob.write(a1);
        //dob.flush();
    } 
    catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally {
        if (dob != null) {
            try {
                dob.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

Eclipse suggested surruonding the .close() with the second try/catch. I may be commiting an obvious mistake, forgive me if that's the case.

Comment: Have you run it in the Eclipse debugger? My guess is that your program doesn't have the rights to access `C:\Users\claudio\` and that it outputs an Exception about that in the Eclipse's Console tab.

Comment: Do you have writing permissions to that directory? Please try to create the file manually.

Comment: I thought it was needless to say there were no exceptions thrown.

Answer (score 0):

Simple,

```
byte[] asd = {65, 22, 123};
FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("C:\Users\claudio\ccc.as");
out.write(data);
out.close();
```

if you are using Java 7+,

```
byte[] asd = {65, 22, 123};
Path file = Paths.get("C:\Users\claudio\ccc.as");
Files.write(file, asd);
```

Answer (score -2):

I'd try [this example](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-create-a-file-in-java/) which uses `createNewFile()` to perform the expected behavior. I don't think the method you're using will create one automatically.

Files can be instantiated using something like the following:

```
File file = new File("MyFile.txt");
file.createNewFile();
```